# Reading parsed JSON into an array doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

I've been working on an application for a while and this particular feature is a part of a function which is supposed to read data from an api into an array so that I can display the contents on a webpage. Right now, I'm stuck here. Originally, I had a much longer section of code that wasn't working, but I've cut it down to a more specific problem: jsonBody.length returns 5, as expected, but articles.length returns 'undefined' and I don't understand why.

```
request(options, function(err, request, body) {
    var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
    var articles = new Article(jsonBody);

    console.log(jsonBody.length);
    console.log(articles.length);

    res.render('news');
});
```

Thank you so much if you could help me understand. I'm not even entirely sure that I'm supposed to be using var articles at all? I can get the JSON to print to the console just find if I use jsonBody, but if I do so, I'm not sure how to utilize the contents on my 'news' page.

Here is the extended code in case you would like to see.

```
var marketNewsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    datetime: String,
    headline: String,
    source: String,
    url: String,
    summary: String,
    related: String,
    Image: String
});

var Article = mongoose.model('MarketNews', marketNewsSchema);

app.get('/api/marketNews', function(req,  res) {
    var query = {
        'symbol': req.body.id
    };

    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/news/last/5',
        method: 'GET',
        qs: query
    };

    request(options, function(err, request, body) {
        var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
        var articles = new Article(jsonBody);

        console.log(jsonBody.length);
        console.log(articles.length);

        res.render('news');
    });
});
```

and the raw JSON object should be in this format:

```
[
    {
        "datetime": "2017-06-29T13:14:22-04:00",
        "headline": "Voice Search Technology Creates A New Paradigm For Marketers",
        "source": "Benzinga via QuoteMedia",
        "url": "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/article/8348646549980454",
        "summary": "<p>Voice search is likely to grow by leap and bounds, with technological advancements leading to better adoption and fueling the growth cycle, according to Lindsay Boyajian, <a href=\"http://loupventures.com/how-the-future-of-voice-search-affects-marketers-today/\">a guest contributor at Loup Ventu...",
        "related": "AAPL,AMZN,GOOG,GOOGL,MSFT",
        "image": "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/news-image/7594023985414148"
    }
]
```

Comment: What happens when you output `console.log(articles[0].length);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that `new Article()` is not an array, but you expect it to be one.

As far as I can see, `Article` is a mongoose schema - not an array.

So if your `jsonBody` is an array of articles, you might want to map over this array and generate individual articles for each object in the list.

I.e.:

```
  var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
  var articles = jsonBody.map(function(data) { 
     return new Article(data);
  })

  console.log(articles.length);
```